# How can I subtract two values based on their ID in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating a table that reads the ID and Revenue from two separate sheets (Sheet1 - ID1, Revenue1 & Sheet2 - ID2, Revenue2) and have created a formula to compare revenues based on ID. How can I subtract Revenue1 from Revenue2 if they are different?

I've tried just subtracting Revenue1 from Revenue2 from the same row, however not all of the ID's match up in that row

Here's the formula so far:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!C2, Sheet1!C:J, 8, FALSE)=Sheet2!J2,
 "Matches", "Doesn't Match"), 0)
```

Where it says "Doesn't Match" is where I'd like the subtraction to happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!C2, Sheet1!C:J, 8, FALSE)=Sheet2!J2,
         "Matches", VLOOKUP(Sheet2!C2, Sheet1!C:J, 8, FALSE)-Sheet2!J2), 0)
```